# Bevel node, baking normal map problem

Tags: node-editor, normals, texture-baking, normal-map, bevel

bevel node is still under development, but maybe somebody know how to fix problem when baking bevel node into normal map, there are a lot of gray dots on the map. Everything else working well, awesome node.
blender-2.79-ef8bbc8-win64
[image: normal map]

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how would you fix it and get a perfect bake, to me it seems like an issue due to ray tracing, where more samples are needed, denoise filter and what not. What you could try: Try to find a denoise filter for Photoshop or whatever ur using and apply it to the normal, see if it fixes it. Also what you can try is playing with blur and then using overlay, difference blend modes to try and patch up those holes with something that works. Maybe copy the normal map, offset it by 1-2 pixels right and up, and use difference blender mode to catch a selection of these dots and then reuse the offset texture to patch it up with those normal base on the difference alpha you get.

Comment: baking normals isn't using ray tracing